# No provision profiles found: can not submit binary

Tags: ios

Any idea what I am missing?

- cleaned provision profiles on developer.apple.com
- cleaned provision profiles in Xcode preferences

[image]

Comment: You are missing valid provisioning profile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution was that

1. in `Developer Portal` in `Provisioning Profiles` I removed all the rows that `status` was not `Active (Managed by Xcode)`
2. In Xcode I refreshed all the Provisioning Profiles then.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following steps to reinstall the certificates and provisioning profiles:

- go to the Apple [Member Center](http://developer.apple.com) and **download** all certificates and provisioning profiles
- **save** them somewhere you can access theme like on desktop
- **double-click** all of them, certificates and profiles
- this will bring up Xcode and the Keychain **close Keychain** as you won't need it anymore
- in Xcode, go to **Build Settings** to verify the profiles were added correctly
- **set** the Developer Code Signing Identity to your profile

All the important files are reinstalled now. Maybe that will fix your problem.

Hope that helps :)